# Conversion React-Redux from v1.x to v2.x

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

So I'm still new and all the tutorials I found used an example with React-Redux v1 but now my code won't even compile giving me this error:
**< Provider > does not support changing `store` on the fly. It is most likely that you see this error because you updated to Redux 2.x and React Redux 2.x which no longer hot reload reducers automatically. See https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/releases/tag/v2.0.0 for the migration instructions.** I tried to follow the example on the link but failed.. This is my code right now before doing any changes:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import firebase from 'firebase';
import ReduxThunk from 'redux-thunk';
import reducers from './reducers';
import AppContainer from './AppNavigator';

console.disableYellowBox = true;

class App extends Component {
    async componentDidMount() {
        const config = {
            apiKey: "",
            authDomain: "",
            databaseURL: "",
            projectId: "",
            storageBucket: "",
            messagingSenderId: ""
          };
        await firebase.initializeApp(config);
    }

    render() {
        const store = createStore(reducers, {}, applyMiddleware(ReduxThunk));

        return (
            <Provider store={store}>
                <AppContainer />
            </Provider>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Why are you creating a new store every single render?!

Comment: this is only on the App.js file , it's how it was shown on the tutorial I followed on Udemy  https://www.udemy.com/the-complete-react-native-and-redux-course/

Comment: Are you sure? Then you should probably not be learning that course

Comment: do you have any suggestions on how to fix it though to at least compile?

Comment: https://github.com/StephenGrider/ReactNativeReduxCasts/blob/master/manager/src/App.js here's his example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem. I had to move the `createStore` line outside the class

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21679973)

Comment: Actually, @richbai90, this apparently _is_ the answer. It's OP posting what he did to solve his own problem. Came up in my review queue, too. I edited the answer a little to make that more clear.